# Concatenating lists into arrays with mypy

Tags: python, numpy, mypy

When using libraries such as numpy I often write code that looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = []
for j in range(10):
    # in a more general case you maybe perform some complex operation here that can't be
    # put into a list comprehension
    a.append(j)

a = np.asarray(a)
```

Unfortunately mypy complains because the type of `a` can't be both a list of ints and an array, and using `Union[List, np.ndarray]` doesn't really work because `append` doesn't exist for arrays. `cast` also doesn't seem to work here, or at least I couldn't find any meaningful way to use it.

I wanted to avoid annotating `a` as `Any` or adding `# type: ignore`, is there any cleaner solution for these use cases? I suppose I could just use a different variable in the end, and do `b = np.asarray(a)` but in this case the garbage collector will probably not get rid of `a` automatically and I would have to delete it manually, also this would be messy for instance if I had a `dict` of lists and I concatenated the lists on a loop, such as:

```
import numpy as np
a = { '0': [0, 1, 2], '1': [0, 1, 2]}

for k, v in a.items():
    v.append(3)
    a[k] = np.asarray(v)
```

Comment: `a = np.concatenate(a)`, should be `a = np.array(a)` instead.

Comment: `concatenate` will complain about a list of integers.  It's a sequence, but the elements are not "array_like".  See the docs. There are lots of `numpy` functions that take a sequence, or array_like, which means anything that can be made into an array.  Have you looked into `numpy's` own `typing` module?

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head with your thing about `b =`. MyPy fundamentally assumes that variables don't change type. You can't say `a = 2` and then `a = "Eggs"` on the next line. The right fix for this is either to use a different variable, or write the code (e.g. with a list comprehension) so that the variable doesn't need storing at all.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, my example is incorrect, I hadn't noticed that, I will update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way around it is to tell mypy to allow redefining the type, either by using the command line with the [`--allow-redefinition`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-allow-redefinition) flag, or to set the [`allow_redefinition=True`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-allow_redefinition) value in the [config file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html)